# Setting the value in a matrix after fill() returns incorrect matrix

Tags: javascript

If I initialize the matrix like

```
x = [["O", "O", "O"], ["O", "O", "O"], ["O", "O", "O"]];
```

And then set
`x[0][1] = "X"`
It returns

```
[ [ 'O', 'X', 'O' ], [ 'O', 'O', 'O' ], [ 'O', 'O', 'O' ] ]
```

as expected

However, if I initialize the matrix as the following:

```
x = new Array(3).fill(new Array(3).fill('O'))
```

And then
`x[0][1] = "X"`
It gives me back

```
[ [ 'O', 'X', 'O' ], [ 'O', 'X', 'O' ], [ 'O', 'X', 'O' ] ]
```

What is going on here?

Comment: You're initializing the "outer" array with a single array in all three "outer" array positions.

Comment: instead fill it with undefined, then use map to populate it: `x = new Array(3).fill().map(a=>new Array(3).fill('O'));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do this:

```
x = [["O", "O", "O"], ["O", "O", "O"], ["O", "O", "O"]];
```

Javascript is creating 3 different Arrays in memory, so when you access `x[0][1]` you're accessing just that array.

When you are using the:

```
x = new Array(3).fill(new Array(3).fill('O'))
```

You are basically filling the array with same array 3 times, so when you access `x[0][1]` you're accessing the same Array in memory that's also connected to `x[1]` and `x[2]`.

As commented by @Shidersz, a possible iterative solution would be:

```
// one liner:
Array.from({length: 3}, x => new Array(3).fill("0"));
```

This is creates an array and populates it with the values returned from the inputed function. Here's a breakdown:

```
// same as previous only longer with comments
// Create an Array from the first argument,
//as modified by the mapping function in the 2nd argument
Array.from(
  // This could be any array like object. 
  // In the case of length it just reads the length property
  // and iterates that number of times,
  // so it could be useful if you want to 
  // fill the top array with 100000 arrays.
  {length: 3},
  // x argument for the mapping is irrelevant
  x => {
    // returning the array with 3 "0" strings in it.
    return  new Array(3).fill("0")
  });
```

[docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) for more reference.

Comment: You can improve this answer showing an alternative way to meet the OP's goal, using: `Array.from({length: 3}, _ => new Array(3).fill("0"))`

Comment: @Shidersz That's a very nice solution i'll add it to the answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this line of code builds an array of three elements, where each element points to the same exact array:

```
x = new Array(3).fill(new Array(3).fill('O'))
```

To help explain, consider this example. Your code is essentially the same as this:

```
innerArray = new Array(3).fill('O');
x = [innerArray, innerArray, innerArray];
```

Note that each element is pointing to the same exact array. If you change the code to this instead, the array will behave the way you expect, because each element is a separate array:

```
x = [new Array(3).fill('O'), new Array(3).fill('O'), new Array(3).fill('O')];
```