# Why do multiple calls of Array.fill effect unreferenced arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Playing around with different ways of instantiating Arrays with Javascript and I noticed some interesting behavior:

```
matrix = Array(3).fill(Array(3).fill(0))
```

Creates an NxN matrix of 0 values

```
[
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0]
]
```

I then tried changing the first row of the matrix to be all 1's:

```
matrix[0].fill(1)
```

Which for some reason turned ALL values in the matrix to 1's:

```
[
  [1,1,1],
  [1,1,1],
  [1,1,1]
]
```

This behavior doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't only the first row be affected by the final call to Array.fill? What's going on here?

Comment: Must be that the internal arrays are all the same? `matrix[0] === matrix[1]` must equate to true.

Comment: because you're filling an array with a reference to the same array 3 times - try `matrix = Array.from({length:3}, () => Array(3).fill(0))` instead - that calls `Array(3).fill(0)` each time, creating a new array for each row

Comment: There is a <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57514341/setting-the-value-in-a-matrix-after-fill-returns-incorrect-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1">similar</a> question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to

```
let row = [0,0,0]
let matrix = [row, row, row];
row.fill(1);
```

because `.fill(Array(3).fill(0))` calls `Array(3).fill(0)` once to get the fill value - if the fill argument were a callback, then it would call it for each item in matrix - but the fill argument is a value

In javascript, arrays are said to be a reference

```
var a = [1,2,3], b=a;
b[0] = 4
```

will result in both `a` and `b` referencing an array with values `[4,2,3]`

so, since each `row` is the same array, your result is as you've seen

try this instead

```js
const matrix = Array.from({length:3}, () => Array(3).fill(0))
matrix[0].fill(1);
console.log(matrix);
```

The above is equivalent to

```
const matrix = [Array(3).fill(0), Array(3).fill(0), Array(3).fill(0)];
matrix[0].fill(1);
```

Now each entry in matrix is a different Array, not the same one each time

Comment: I had a feeling it was something along the lines of this. Thanks for the thorough explanation!