# Unexpected result with 2d array - whole column is changed

Tags: javascript, matrix, multidimensional-array

Given a 3x3 matrix I want to set the element in the first row, 3rd column to `true`.

I would expect that `m[0][2] = true` would do it, but it does not. It sets the whole column to true!

My code to create the array and set the value is below. What caused this behavior?

```js
const size = 3;

const m = Array(size).fill(Array(size).fill(false))

console.log(m); 
/* [[false, false, false], 
    [false, false, false], 
    [false, false, false]]
*/

m[0][2] = true;

console.log(m);
/*
   [[false, false, true], 
    [false, false, true], 
    [false, false, true]]
*/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array.fill(Array) creates copies by references not by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949813/array-fillarray-creates-copies-by-references-not-by-value)

Comment: The behaviour you describe is already *telling* you that they're the same reference. That specific dupe suggestion is just one of many signposts around this behaviour with Array.fill - https://stackoverflow.com/q/27613126/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/60432172/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/57514341/3001761, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are filling the first array with the same array in every spot.

```js
let array1 = [false, false, false];
let array2 = array1;
array1[2] = true;
console.log(array2);
```

Use Array.from

```js
let size = 3;
let m = Array.from({ length: size }, _ => Array.from({ length: size }, _ => false));
console.log(m);
m[0][2] = true;
console.log(m);
```

This way you have a different instance of an array in each slot of the top level array.

You could use Array.fill in the function as false is a value object not a reference object.

```js
let size = 3;
let m = Array.from({ length: size }, _ => Array(size).fill(false));
console.log(m);
m[0][2] = true;
console.log(m);
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Didn't know that fill passed the values by reference

Answer (score -1):

7 Ways to create 2D matrices in JavaScript:

One liners:

```js
const size = 3;
const val = null;

const m1 = Array(size).fill(Array(size).fill(val)); // issue: rows are all the same.
const m2 = Array(size).fill([...Array(size).fill(val)]); // issue: rows are the same;

const m3 = Array(size).fill().map(_ => Array(size).fill(val));
const m4 = Array.from(Array(size), _ => Array(size).fill(val));

const m5 = Array.from({length: size}, _ => Array.from({length: size}, _ => val))
```

All of these will create size x size matrices. However, using `Array.fill` directly will create copies by reference and not by value (e.g. `m1` and `m2`). You can use `Array.fill` inside a mapper function to fix the issue (e.g. `m3`, `m4`, and `m7`). Finally, you can create matrices using `Array.from` twice.

There are 2 more ways of creating matrices but not as elegant.

Using for loops:

```js
const m6 = [];
for(let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    m6[i] = [];
    for(let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        m6[i][j] = val;
    }
}

const m7 = Array(size);
for(let i = 0; i < m7.length; i++) {
    m7[i] = Array(size).fill(val);
}
```